# image not loading in javascript with onpage_scroll

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jquery-plugins

Hello I want to use a season script using the [onepage-scroll](https://github.com/peachananr/onepage-scroll) jquery plugin. But the images are not loading. What do I have to do? The "page1" class have to show the images.

The HTML

```
<div class="wrapper">
   <div class="main">`

     <section class="page1">
        <div class="page_container">

    </div>
    </section>
 </div>
</div>
```

The javascript in the head tag

```
  $(document).ready(function(){
  $(".main").onepage_scroll({
    sectionContainer: "section"
  });
    });

          function seasonalBackground(node,images)
  {

    switch(new Date().getMonth())
    {
      case 2: case 3: case 4: //maart april mei
        img = 1;
        break;
      case 5: case 6: case 7: //juni juli augustus
        img = 2;
        break;
      case 8: case 9: case 10: //september oktober november
        img = 3;
        break;
      default: //december januari februari 
        img = 0;
    }

    node.style.backgroundImage = "url(\""+images[img]+"\")";

  }
```

Javascript before end body tag

```
 var imgArray = new Array();
  imgArray[0] = "images/winter.jpg";
  imgArray[1] = "images/spring.jpg";
  imgArray[2] = "images/summer.jpg";
  imgArray[3] = "images/autumn.jpg";

  seasonalBackground(document.getElementByClass('page1'),imgArray);
```

Comment: Please create a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net).

Comment: Look in the [JavaScript error console](http://www.netmagazine.com/tutorials/javascript-debugging-beginners). I bet there's an error about `getElementByClass` not being a function.

Comment: since you have jQuery, why not use it: `$('.page1')` or `$('.page1:first')` ? and then `node.css('background-image', "url('"+images[img]+"')")`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in your function, you should declare your javascript variable using `var` to keep them local instead of using them directly

Also, the function `getElementByClass` does not exists. you have to replace it by `getElementsByClassName`

```
seasonalBackground(document.getElementsByClassName('page1')[0],imgArray);
```

Maybe there is others errors, open the javascript console of your browser to see if there is errors

Comment: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'backgroundImage' of undefined index.html:34
event.returnValue is deprecated. Please use the standard event.preventDefault() instead. This are the errors i got

Comment: yes sorry, I forgot the `[0]` because getElementsByClassName return an array, not only one element. Just edited

Answer (score 0):

```
document.getElementsByClass('page1');
```

**not**

```
document.getElementByClass('page1');
```

then focus on first element ?

```
document.getElementsByClass('page1')[0];
```

So finally all...

```
seasonalBackground(document.getElementsByClass('page1')[0],imgArray);
```

*If your code are ok.*